# Cyclic finite groups and their direct product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Let $C$ be a cyclic group with three elements. prove that $C \times C \times C$ can not be generated by two elements.
I was thinking that showing that $C ^{3}$ is isomorphic to ${\mathbb{Z}_{3}} ^{3}$ will get me somewhere but I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $a,b\in C\times C\times C$ are two nonidentity elements. Then the order of $a$ and $b$ is 3 because this is true of each nonidentity coordinate. The subgroup generated by $a$ and $b$ consists of all elements of the form $a^pb^q$ where $0\leq p,q\leq 2$. This subgroup has at most $9$ elements and hence cannot be the whole group, which  has $27$ elements.

Comment: Ok. that's brilliant, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Uria You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Uria, your original idea also works. $\mathbb Z_3$ is also a *field*, $(\mathbb Z_3)^3$ is a three-dimensional *vector space* over it, and it's subgroups are the same as its linear subspaces. Now you only have to refer to the fact that every vector space has a dimension (three in this case) and can not be generated by
fewer elements.